# Error when trying to get the element's style attribute using the html console

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get the value of an element in the DOM.
I would like to get the "Active" value in the style attribute:

```
<span ng-class="{'megatable-filter-box-txt-selected' : filter.value.length > 0}" class="ng-binding megatable-filter-box-txt-selected" style="">Active</span>
```

On the console I tried to get it by:

```
    element = $("[sf-name='stateFilter']")        
    document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(element)
```

I got an error of:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'. at <anonymous>:1:22

What am I doing wrong? What is the way to get the value?

Answer (score 3):

The object in your element isn't an element object. If the site includes jQuery it's a jQuery object.

Try using:
`document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(element[0])`

You can access the DOM element objects within a jQuery object by treating it like an array, pulling the DOM element objects out using indexes.

If that code works, it means that it's a jQuery object with at least 1 DOM element matching the selector.

Answer (score 0):

> parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.

This method expects the reference to a DOM element, but you passed in a jQuery object.

You need to get the reference to the DOM element you have selected via jQuery first, which can for example be done simply by using the index:

```
document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(element[0])
```